# Cross domain JSONP AJAX - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I am building a simple app for a platform called Mixi, which is like Facebook in Japan. Now, in the Javascript API I am trying to fetch user's profile information as per given API and after passing the correct auth token.

The API link works perfect if I trigger it from my address bar in the browser. But, after hours of fiddling with it, and trying JSONP and all possible variants which I could find, Chrome's console does show data but only when I click on this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Now, I can not change anything on the server side since it is a public API and I need to access it cross-origin. If response is JSON and not JSONP, which I think is the case, what can be done to work around ? What's the way out in this case ?

My call looks like this:

```
// token is coming correctly from code above
var reqUrl = "https://api.mixi-platform.com/2/people/@me/@self?access_token=" + token;

$.ajax({
           type:'GET',
           url: reqUrl,
           processData: true,
           data: {},
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function (data) {
               alert("Success");
               alert(data);
           },
           error: function() { alert("not working..."); },
           jsonp: 'jsonp'
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `crossDomain:true` setting?

Comment: I'm looking at the MIXI documentation and I only see API responses formatted in JSON, not JSONP. This means, because of the Same Origin Policy, you cannot access their data like you have. I'm not an expert, so maybe somebody else can verify this, but I believe you will need to use a server-side language to connect with their API. In PHP, I would use something called `CURL` or `FileGetContents()` to receive the JSON response. You could still use AJAX to call your server, which then makes the API request, and then you can send the JSON back to your page and process the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the social network you're requesting data from have CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) enabled, you cannot use AJAX to get JSON formatted data from them, as it falls foul of the Same Origin Policy (SOP). You can, however, request JSONP, cross origin, as that doesn't come under the SOP ruling, but after looking at their documentation, they don't provide JSONP formatted responses.

If you have a look at their documentation's sample code page, [here](http://developer.mixi.co.jp/en/connect/mixi_graph_api/mixi_io_spec_top/examples/), you will see the list of languages supported. If Javascript/jQuery was one of them, you would think they'd give you an example somewhere.

[image]

I believe you need to use a server-side language to request data from them. I don't think you can use AJAX. If you're using PHP, you could use `CURL` or `fileGetContents()`. I have pasted a PHP example below, which can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mixi-inc/mixi_graph_api_examples/blob/master/PHP/sample.php).

**PHP Example**

```
<?php
define('CONSUMER_KEY', '[YOUR CONSUMER KEY]');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '[YOUR CONSUMER SECRET]');
define('REDIRECT_URI', '[YOUR REDIRECT URI]');

class MixiGraphAPIExample
{
    const MIXI_API_ENDPOINT = 'http://api.mixi-platform.com/2';
    const MIXI_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'https://secure.mixi-platform.com/2/token';

    private $token;

    public function __construct($auth_code) {
        $this->authorize($auth_code);
    }

    private function post($uri, $data) {
        $context = array('http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => http_build_query($data, null, '&'),
            'ignore_errors' => true,
        ));
        $body = file_get_contents($uri, false, stream_context_create($context));
        $header = $this->parseHeader($http_response_header);
        if ($this->isHttpFail($header['Status'])) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Post Request Fail:'.PHP_EOL.$uri.PHP_EOL.var_export($header, true));
        }
        return $body;
    }

    private function authorize($auth_code) {
        $data = array(
             'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
             'client_id' => CONSUMER_KEY,
             'client_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET,
             'code' => $auth_code,
             'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,
        );
        $this->token = json_decode($this->post(self::MIXI_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, $data), true);
    }

    private function refreshToken() {
        $data = array(
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'client_id' => CONSUMER_KEY,
            'client_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET,
            'refresh_token' => $this->token['refresh_token'],
        );
        $this->token = json_decode($this->post(self::MIXI_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, $data), true);
    }

    private function parseHeader($headers) {
        $statusLine = array_shift($headers);
        list(, $result['Status'], ) = explode(' ', $statusLine);
        foreach ($headers as $header) {
            list($key, $value) = explode(': ', $header);
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function isHttpFail($status) {
        return (bool)(empty($status) || ($status >= 400));
    }

    private function isExpired($headers) {
        $result = false;
        if (array_key_exists('WWW-Authenticate', $headers)) {
            if (preg_match('/expired_token/', $headers['WWW-Authenticate'])) {
                $result = true;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function call($location) {
        static $retry_count = 0;

        $uri = self::MIXI_API_ENDPOINT . $location . '?oauth_token=' . $this->token['access_token'];
        $response = file_get_contents($uri, false, stream_context_create(array('http' => array('ignore_errors' => true))));
        $header = $this->parseHeader($http_response_header);

        if ($this->isHttpFail($header['Status'])) {
            if ($this->isExpired($header)) {
                if ($retry_count++ > 1) {
                    throw new RangeException('Token Refresh Too many retry. '.PHP_EOL.var_export($this->token, true).PHP_EOL.var_export($header, true));
                }

                $this->refreshToken();
                $response = $this->call($location);
                $retry_count = 0;
            } else {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid API Access:'.PHP_EOL.$uri.PHP_EOL.var_export($header, true));
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }

    public function execute($endpoint) {
        return json_decode($this->call($endpoint), true);
    }

    public static function getInstance($auth_code) {
        return new self($auth_code);
    }
}

if (debug_backtrace()) return;
if ($_SERVER['argc'] != 2) {
    exit("Please input your Authorization Code\n Usage : {$_SERVER['argv'][0]} [YOUR AUTHORIZATION CODE]\n");
}

try {
    $response = \MixiGraphAPIExample::getInstance($_SERVER['argv'][1])->execute('/people/@me/@self');
    var_dump($response);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Will try to use CURL (PHP) to fetch data from Mixi and call the API on the game server's end using JavaScript afterwards.